# Using path variable in Thymeleaf th:replace

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using a path variable in my controller to swap out content on an HTML page, the following works fine for me and is the rout I was going:

```
Controller:
@RequestMapping(path = "/p/{request}", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public String index(@PathVariable("request") String request, Model model) {
    System.out.println(request);
    model.addAttribute("pageName", request);
    return "pages/index";
}

The div:
<div class="col-xs-10 dev-outline">
    <!-- begin content -->
    <div th:replace="fragments/page-content :: ${pageName}"></div>
</div>
```

This works fine, and allows me to have one html file (fragments/page-content.html) to hold all of the data that I need.

However it's becoming clear that as the content grows, I don't want a 2k line html file holding all the content, and for maintainabilities sake I would rather have one file for each of the page contents.

I tried the following and found that it does not work the way I expected it to:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 dev-outline">
    <!-- begin content -->
    <div th:replace="fragments/${pageName} :: content"></div>
</div>
```

I thought this would let me make new html pages and label the div inside with "content", but Thymleaf can't parse it.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?  Or am I thinking about this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out... I needed to replace:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/${pageName} :: content"></div>
```

with:

```
<div th:replace="${pageName} :: content"></div>
```

and just prepend "fragments/" in the controller.

Comment: For reference, `th:replace="'fragments/' + ${pageName} :: content"` should work also, using a Thymeleaf string literal with concatenation ([reference](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#standard-expression-syntax)).

Comment: Thanks for the reference!  That's really helpful